# gtk+ : GtkFileChooserDialog hide some widgets

Tags: c, gtk

I have a little problem with the GtkFileChooserDialog.

I Want to hide the favoris panel (widget on the left).

So I start to get the GtkVBox of the GtkFileChooserDialog,
and now I Want to retrive it's child and hite it,
but I don't find it's children.

Here is my code :

```
my_dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new("Hop", NULL, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL);
button = gtk_file_chooser_button_new_with_dialog(my_dialog);

children_dial = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(my_dialog));
v_dial = GTK_VBOX(children_dial->data);

v_children = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(v_dial));
```

So if anyone has an idea,

thanks.

Comment: I'd encourage you to look into gtk+ code. And some hints. *GtkFileChooseDialog* is *GtkDialog* that packs a *GtkFileChooserWidget* in its *content-area*. So I suggest you to read how it's implemented the *GtkFileChooserWidget*, and dig through its code. A tiny lead, the code you're looking for is in *gtkfilechooserdefault.c*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The children of the `GtkFileChooserDialog` and `GtkFileChooserWidget` are "internal" children which means you can't retrieve them like that. You aren't supposed to mess with them, since they may be implemented differently in a future version. However, you can access them with [`gtk_container_forall()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkContainer.html#gtk-container-forall).

Why do you want to hide the favorites panel? Unless you have a really good reason, it is bad user interface design to change the standard file dialog that users expect, just because you don't like the panel on the left.